# Which one is ExternalTrigger in BABE?

Tags: babe, session, timestamp, pos

in this [document](https://crates.parity.io/src/pallet_babe/lib.rs.html#18-975) it mentioned `ExternalTrigger`. So which pallet could be `ExternalTrigger` for BABE. and How to implement `EpochChangeTrigger`?

It also said that `pallet-session` could be used, but `pallet-session` doesn't have `EpochChangeTrigger`. so How `pallet-session` and `pallet-babe` work with each other when there is new session/epoch?